# Lineup children side-by-side inside absolutely positioned parent?

Tags: position, css-float, css-position, css

My drop-down menu requires the use of `position: absolute;` for the dropdown. And inside the drop-down, I want to have menu items in multiple columns, like so ([example](http://www.itwire.com/)):

[image: Mega menu]

For that I could use either `float` or `display: inline-block;`, but actually, none work as the absolutely positioned parent simply collapses, and the children are lined up below each other, instead of next to each other.

How can I achieve what I need without having to set a specific `width` or `height` on the parent or its children? Is there no way around?

I did try a lot of solutions from similar questions, and those that worked need me to set a specific width or height or have the parent extend to the full width of the page.

Comment: when you used float did you put a clear in after the floated elements?

Comment: @Pete Yes. The parent was still collapsed. I also tried the `.clearfix` on the parent itself as one of the answers suggested. Still didn't work.